# What is the right way to create development and production environments for a network of servers in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to deploy multiple machines across various geographical regions to serve my application in a Development and Production environment; I'm coming from Google Cloud Platform where my solution would be to create 2 projects:

- `project-dev`
- `project-prod`

With that I have complete freedom of creating resources in any region/zone in either project/environment.

The closest thing to this I have found on Azure is Resource Groups, but those are tied to a specified region, which is not ideal for me. Is there a better way, rather than creating a resource group in EACH region I choose to deploy resources for both environments as follows:

- `project-dev-east-us`
- `project-dev-west-us`
- `project-dev-west-eu`
- `project-dev-east-as`
- `project-prod-east-us`
- `project-prod-west-us`
- `project-prod-west-eu`
- `project-prod-east-as`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource groups are tied to regions, but resource inside are not, so you can have resources from multiple regions in a single resource group. but resource group is like a folder on a hard drive. its just a way to logically organize things, nothing more.

Comment: The location of a resource group is just where its metadata is stored.